# “Error loading RubyGems plugin” while inside a Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

In my Rails Engine, I get an "Error Loading RubyGems." However, this error doesn't persist when I'm in the root directory of my app.

From my main Rails folder:

```
$ gem -v
2.0.5
```

From inside the engine:

```
$ gem -v
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.2.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.1/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.1/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.1/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
2.0.5
```

This is preventing me from running bundle install, rails server, etc.

I'm stumped. I haven't been able to find anyone with the same issue, and have run out of leads on what I think it could be for the night. Thanks...

Comment: Try these commands from inside engine directory i.e project/test/dummy or project/spec/dummy

Comment: @AmanGarg It's the same error from inside spec/dummy

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was a lack of .ruby-version file in my engine directory. Just adding this file ended up fixing the problem.